# ZXing.NET UPC_A Extensions

Tags: barcode, zxing.net

I'm trying to decode barcodes on magazines and comic books. These guys sometimes have an "extension" of 2 or 5 digits stored in a slightly separated code; it is used to encode things like the issue number. It's described [here](https://www.barcode.graphics/guidance-for-upc-barcodes-for-comic-books/).

I have this sample image: [image]

In my application, I've written this proof of concept method:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    string barcode = string.Empty;
    using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {

        try
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using var coreCompatImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
            var coreCompatReader = new ZXing.Windows.Compatibility.BarcodeReader();
            coreCompatReader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.UPC_A };
            var coreCompatResult = coreCompatReader.Decode(coreCompatImage);
            var multipleCodes = coreCompatReader.DecodeMultiple(coreCompatImage);
            barcode = coreCompatResult?.Text ?? string.Empty;
        }    
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return "Error processing the image: ";
        }
    }
    return barcode;
}
```

I was hoping `multipleCodes` would pick up both barcodes, but I only get the first 12 digits.

How do I convince ZXing to return "75966066620843200131" instead of "759660666208432"?

Comment: the supported formats for the original library https://github.com/zxing/zxing?tab=readme-ov-file#supported-formats suggests that Extension 2/5 formats are implemented as `ITF` rather than `code39`.  I would suggest trying `BarcodeFormat.ITF` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for looking @Claies - I did just ITF and got a null result. I decided to try UPC_EAN_Extension and that got me back to the first set. The code is currently `coreCompatReader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.UPC_A, BarcodeFormat.UPC_EAN_EXTENSION, BarcodeFormat.ITF };` and I only get the first 12 digits.